# PayPal recurring payments with Trial period

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, paypal, trial

I'm trying to implement PayPal subscriptions system with following features:

- 1st month of service on the application would be completely free after which user will pay monthly amount.

I have written the following code like below:

```
BillingPeriodType periodType = BillingPeriodType.MONTH;
                    switch (subs)
                    {
                        case("Month"):
                            periodType = BillingPeriodType.MONTH;
                            break;
                        case("Year"):
                            periodType = BillingPeriodType.YEAR;
                            break;
                    }
                    BasicAmountType paymentAmount = new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("USD", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), subType.Price);
                    BillingPeriodType period = periodType;
                    BillingPeriodDetailsType paymentPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(period, 1, paymentAmount);
                    ScheduleDetailsType scheduleDetails = new ScheduleDetailsType();

                    /*Free trial period of 1 month for monthly sub*/
                    if (periodType == BillingPeriodType.MONTH)
                    {
                        scheduleDetails.TrialPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(BillingPeriodType.MONTH,1, new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("USD", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "0.01"));
                        scheduleDetails.TrialPeriod.TotalBillingCycles = 1;
                    }
                    else if (periodType == BillingPeriodType.YEAR)
                    {
                        scheduleDetails.TrialPeriod = new BillingPeriodDetailsType(BillingPeriodType.YEAR, 1, new BasicAmountType((CurrencyCodeType)EnumUtils.GetValue("USD", typeof(CurrencyCodeType)), "0.01"));

                    }

                    scheduleDetails.Description = "//Some description"
                    scheduleDetails.PaymentPeriod = paymentPeriod;
                    createRPProfileRequest.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequestDetails.ScheduleDetails = scheduleDetails;
                    CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq createRPProfileReq = new CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileReq();
                    createRPProfileReq.CreateRecurringPaymentsProfileRequest = createRPProfileRequest;
```

This raises to me a huge security concern...

```
So let's suppose user subscribes for monthly subscription and get 1 month for free... 

This way, nothing stops the user to cancel the subscription the last day and then to re-subscribe once again and re-use the 1 month trial period for free...
```

Currently of the users's information on PayPal I only store ProfileID information into the DB....

Is there any efficient way to see if the user has used free trial period on my website?

```
Also another security concern to me is that user can simply re-register with new account and subscribe once again under completely different ProfileID
```

How would you guys solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I just hope I don't misunderstood your question:

Why don't you link the users PayPal e-mail address to the registered account? In this case the user has to use a different paypal account, so it's much easier to avoid people like this.

And at the users registration, the users should already provide his billing informations. Including his PayPal e-mail address.

Comment: Phillip, good point, but what if user adds multiple email addresses to his paypal account and changes the new one to primary (this is possible) ? =)

Comment: Oh, I thought that's not possible. Does the PayPal API don't provide unique user informations?

Comment: I believe it does, then I'd have to check his first & last name and pre-existing subscription profiles to see if he had trial periods , no ?\

Comment: If you have a unique user identification, you can easily avoid him to create another account and at the same account it shouldn't be possible to make a 2nd trial of course. There should be only one account with one and the same paypal user identification.

Comment: Looking at my IPN log, I see payer_id, which is the 13 digit paypal ID that I believe cannot be changed, short of creating a new paypal account. If they're going to create a new paypal account just for your free trial, well, I guess you can take comfort in knowing your service is really good :)